# Unable to send email message on behalf of another O365 outlook account

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

For some reason the 'Send on Behalf' feature is failing for me. Graph always returns an **ErrorSendAsDenied** (when `From` and `Sender` field values are different).

The accounts are verified to have the correct configuration for sending on behalf of each other. I couldn't make it work after spending more than three days on it.

Following permissions are requested during authentication:

- `openid`
- `email`
- `profile`
- `offline_access`
- `User.Read`
- `Mail.Read`
- `Mail.ReadWrite`
- `Mail.Read.Shared`
- `Mail.ReadWrite.Shared`
- `Mail.Send`
- `Mail.Send.Shared`

For the example below, the user Gregory Test wants to send messages on behalf of Sem Test. A valid authorization access token (authenticated by Gregory Test) is used for sending the email, however email delivery ALWAYS fails.

The sample submitted JSON message is:

```json
{
   "Message":{
      "Subject":"Trying to send message on behalf",
      "Body":{
         "ContentType":"html",
         "Content":" email html content "
      },
      "From":{
         "EmailAddress":{
            "Address":"sem.test@contoso.com",
            "Name":"Sem Test"
         }
      },
      "Sender":{
         "EmailAddress":{
            "Address":"gregory.test@contoso.com",
            "Name":"Gregory Test"
         }
      },
      "ToRecipients":[
         {
            "EmailAddress":{
               "Address":"semtestestestes@gmail.com",
               "Name":"Sem Shehovtsov"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

If the `Sender` and `From` are set to the same value, it is working fine. The `Sender` mailbox is configured to allow sending messages on behalf of other users.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the `Sender` property, Graph will handle this automatically for you. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-send-mail-from-other-user#sending-with-microsoft-graph):

> In order to send from another user, set the `from` property on the message sent to the email address of the user to send from. You don't need to set the `sender` property - Microsoft Graph will set it appropriately, based on the mailbox permissions granted to the user who has signed in.

Try this payload instead:

```
{
   "message":{
      "subject": "Trying to send message on behalf",
      "body":{
         "contentType":"html",
         "content":" email html content "
      },
      "toRecipients":[
         {
            "emailAddress":{
               "address":"semtestestestes@gmail.com",
               "name":"Sem Shehovtsov"
            }
         }
      ],
      "from":{
         "emailAddress":{
            "address":"sem.test@contoso.com",
            "name":"Sem Test"
         }
      },
   }
}
```

Also, you don't need to request *both* `Read` and `ReadWrite` scopes. The `ReadWrite` scopes overlap with the `Read` scopes.

Comment: removing "sender" section doesn't change anything.